# Parallelize function in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am pretty new to R, and have never attempted parallel computing before. I'm using the following functions to find perfect numbers (I know this is not the not the most efficient way of finding perfect numbers, since using Mersanne Primes is a lot faster):

```
factorlist <- function(n) {
  if(n < 1) {return("Invalid input: n must be a natural number")}
  if(n%%1 != 0) {return("Invalid input: n must be a natural number")}
  div <- 0
  if(n%%2 != 0) {
    for(i in seq(1, n-1, by = 2)) {
      if(n%%i == 0) {
        div[length(div)] <- i
        div <- c(div, 0)
      }
    }
    div <- div[-length(div)]
    return(div)
  }
  if(n%%2 == 0) {
    for(i in seq(1, n-1)) {
      if(n%%i == 0) {
        div[length(div)] <- i
        div <- c(div, 0)
      }
    }
    div <- div[-length(div)]
    return(div)
  }
}

perfectcheckN <- function(n) {
  if(n < 1) {return("Invalid input: n must be a natural number")}
  if(n%%1 != 0) {return("Invalid input: n must be a natural number")}
  start.time <- Sys.time()
  perf <- 0
  for(i in 6:n) {
    div <- factorlist(i)
    num <- 0
    for(j in 1:length(div)) {
      num <- num + div[j]
    }
    if(num == i) {
      perf[length(perf)] <- num
      perf <- c(perf, 0)
    }
  }
  perf <- perf[-length(perf)]
  end.time <- Sys.time()
  time.taken <- end.time - start.time
  return(cat(perf, "Time taken:", time.taken, "seconds."))
}
```

My CPU has 12 threads, and running this code normally uses a single thread and takes a very long time with large inputs. Is there a way to parallelize the code to make it run faster? Thanks in advance

Comment: @RomanLuštrik is that comment for this question?

Comment: I must have had two windows open and pasted the comment to the wrong question, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Initial Approach

One simple approach without much code changes would be to use `parallel::mclapply` *assuming* you are not on Windows (if you are look at [parallelsugar::mclapply](https://www.r-bloggers.com/parallelsugar-an-implementation-of-mclapply-for-windows/) for a Windows implementation). However this is not ideal since it pre-schedules the numbers into buckets for each thread. For example if we have the number 40000 on a 4 core machine the buckets would be something like:

- the first `6:10000`
- the second `10001:20000`
- the third `20001:30000`
- the fourth `30001:40000`

The first 3 threads will finish before the last one. However, this will be faster than your original. A single run using my **4 core** non-hyperthreaded Intel i5 3570K gives me the following results:

```
perfectcheckN(10000)

mclapply version: 6 28 496 8128 Time taken: 5.015653 seconds.
original version: 6 28 496 8128 Time taken: 14.84113 seconds.
speedup: 2.96x
```

Code:

```
library(parallel)

factorlist <- function(n) {
  if(n < 1) {return("Invalid input: n must be a natural number")}
  if(n%%1 != 0) {return("Invalid input: n must be a natural number")}
  div <- 0
  if(n%%2 != 0) {
    for(i in seq(1, n-1, by = 2)) {
      if(n%%i == 0) {
        div[length(div)] <- i
        div <- c(div, 0)
      }
    }
    div <- div[-length(div)]
    return(div)
  }
  if(n%%2 == 0) {
    for(i in seq(1, n-1)) {
      if(n%%i == 0) {
        div[length(div)] <- i
        div <- c(div, 0)
      }
    }
    div <- div[-length(div)]
    return(div)
  }
}

perfectcheckN <- function(n) {
  if(n < 1) {return("Invalid input: n must be a natural number")}
  if(n%%1 != 0) {return("Invalid input: n must be a natural number")}
  start.time <- Sys.time()

  perf <- mclapply(6:n, mc.cores = detectCores(), FUN = function(i) {
    div <- factorlist(i)
    num <- 0
    for(j in 1:length(div)) {
      num <- num + div[j]
    }
    if(num == i) {
      return(num)
    }
    return(NA)
  })
  perf <- t(as.data.frame(perf[!is.na(perf)]))
  perf <- c(perf, 0)
  perf <- perf[-length(perf)]
  end.time <- Sys.time()
  time.taken <- end.time - start.time
  return(cat(perf, "Time taken:", time.taken, "seconds."))
}
```

### A Better Approach

`mclapply` has a `mc.preschedule` option we can set to `F` but this won't help since it does each integer per thread (instead of a range). However we can randomly sample `6:n` to have all threads run for about the same time (and we'll need to sort `perf` to get the same order). Anyway, this will help a great deal. Beyond this, I'd look into optimizing the way you wrote the R code, but that isn't the question you were asking (but it too would speed things up).

```
perfectcheckN(10000)

mclapply version: 6 28 496 8128 Time taken: 4.393636 seconds.
original version: 6 28 496 8128 Time taken: 14.84113 seconds.
speedup: 3.38x
```

Updated Code:

```
library(parallel)

factorlist <- function(n) {
  if(n < 1) {return("Invalid input: n must be a natural number")}
  if(n%%1 != 0) {return("Invalid input: n must be a natural number")}
  div <- 0
  if(n%%2 != 0) {
    for(i in seq(1, n-1, by = 2)) {
      if(n%%i == 0) {
        div[length(div)] <- i
        div <- c(div, 0)
      }
    }
    div <- div[-length(div)]
    return(div)
  }
  if(n%%2 == 0) {
    for(i in seq(1, n-1)) {
      if(n%%i == 0) {
        div[length(div)] <- i
        div <- c(div, 0)
      }
    }
    div <- div[-length(div)]
    return(div)
  }
}

perfectcheckN <- function(n) {
  if(n < 1) {return("Invalid input: n must be a natural number")}
  if(n%%1 != 0) {return("Invalid input: n must be a natural number")}
  start.time <- Sys.time()

  perf <- mclapply(sample(6:n), mc.cores = detectCores(), FUN = function(i) {
    div <- factorlist(i)
    num <- 0
    for(j in 1:length(div)) {
      num <- num + div[j]
    }
    if(num == i) {
      return(num)
    }
    return(NA)
  })
  perf <- t(as.data.frame((perf[!is.na(perf)])))
  perf <- c(perf, 0)
  perf <- perf[-length(perf)]
  end.time <- Sys.time()
  time.taken <- end.time - start.time
  return(cat(sort(perf), "Time taken:", time.taken, "seconds."))
}
```